# PHP MySQL - Number of rows with column value between X and Y, is there a better way?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table with all of the visitors to my website. Each visitor is recorded with the time() they visited the website.

I am trying to quickly display the number of visitors for each hour...like

Hour 1: 5 visitors

Hour 2: 7 visitors

etc...

Right now, this is the function I am using. It is working fine, but it seems very tedious and I was wondering if there's an easier way maybe with the group by?

```
while($start_time<$end_time){
$end_of_hour=$start_time+3600;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE time>'$start_time' AND time<'$end_of_hour'");
echo "Visitors this hour: ".mysql_num_rows($query);
$start_time=$start_time+3600;   
}
```

Is there a better way? Or is this the easiest way to do it. Thanks!:)

Comment: there are ways to do it using *GROUP BY*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)), count(*) FROM visitors WHERE time between ('$start_time', '$end_time') group BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```

It seems that your time is unix epoch, so convert it to MySQL Datetime type first, get the hour part, and group by the hour.And make it only select the timeframe within your start time and end time.

Comment: Counting it would benefit CPU time for your PHP script, to a small degree. Don't forget about the BETWEEN operator in MySQL as well. That will help to "clean up" the query as well, in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the answer! but I am not sure how I would display this? How does the start_time and end_time play into it? Thanks again.

Comment: Modified my answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for doing that:) So now, I just do the same While loop again but this will decrease server load?

Comment: You dont need the while loop, just run this query and fetch every row in the result set, and it will bring you by-hour visitor counts(ex: 15pm x visitor, 16pm y visitor). But if you want some thing like '15:25~16:25, 16:25~17:25 visitor count', then the query has to be modified